# delete tableview cell when navigation bake from View controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my iOS app I am using Core Data to show data on a table view this is working fine .

what i want to do is :

when clicking  on the navigation back button of view controller i want

to delete tableview cell if the textview on the View controller is empty .

i want to do it like Apple note app .

can any one hellp me with sample code please

here is my code to check if textview is empty or not

```
if( self.info .text.length  <= 0 ){


}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you encountered problems? PLease read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure your DataSource is something like this a

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWitObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",nil];
```

2.Remove wanted objects from your dataSource like so

```
[dataSource  removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

**Delete rows in UITableView with animation**

Create indexPaths to delete like this

```
NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
        nil];
```

Finally delete them from the tableView like this

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Or you can simply call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: thanks for your help but can u explain more i am new on programming ios

Comment: I have edited the code to be little bit more descriptive

Comment: thanks for your help but this does not work with me i am trying to delete the selected row when i navigation back from view countroller if the textview is empty .


is there a way to delete a tableview row from anotherview like in apple not app ??? if the textview text was delete  and you click the navgition button back you will see that the selected row was deleted .

Comment: Before you dismiss your ViewController check your textField and if empty delete your NSManagedObject from your CoreData

Comment: thank u thank u thank u 

this is the code that fix the problem with your great help 

if( self.info .text.length  <= 0 ){

self.managedObjectContext = editDetails.managedObjectContext;
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:editDetails];

}